# How to set 'sender' while sending email using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send email using Node Js. I am able to send email but I am not sure how to get 'sender'working. As per documentation mentioned [here](https://nodemailer.com/message/) I tried adding sender as part of message but  I dont see 'sender' in received email. I got 'replyTo' option working which is again a advanced field like 'sender'. Has any one tried this and got 'sender' in received email message ?

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'xyz@rr.com',
    to: 'raje@gmail.com',
    cc: 'abc@ee.com',
    sender: 'siddhesh@ff.com',
    replyTo : 'abc@ff.com',
    subject: 'sender test'};
```

Comment: Gmail replaces sender field by from please read this link  https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

Comment: Ok but the issue is with Office 365 too and even Domino

Answer (score 0):

Sender' support has been discontinued by most of the email servers as there can be confusion over identity of actual sender.If you are  going by RFC, it might take longer to update in latest version. Still you can try retrieving email using  IMAP and see if it appears

Comment: Thanks Girish. But I don't find any official note about its discontinuity other than for Gmail as mentioned above by Kalleshwar Kalshetty